# LitElement and Webpack - How to load the web components?

Tags: webpack, web-component, lit-element

I'm about 1 day into my professional experience with LitElement and web components.  I have tried searching for an answer to this but haven't been successful yet, and of course I have deadlines.

I'm writing a component library with a pure Typescript interface.  For all intents and purposes, the host can call an API method to create an instance of my window given an HTMLElement as a parent node.  I have defined a LitElement-based web component in a file:

```
// main-element.ts
import * as Lit from 'lit-element';    

export class MainElement extends Lit.LitElement {
  createRenderRoot() {
    return this; // Don't use shadow root
  }

  render() {
    return Lit.html`
      <div>
        Hello, world!
      </div>
    `;
  }
}

window.customElements.define('main-element', MainElement);

declare global {
  interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
    'main-element': MainElement;
  }
}
```

In my 'module.ts' file ( which handles the API method ), it tries to create an instance of this internal web component:

```
// module.ts
// ...

createWindow(context: MyWindowContext): void {
  context.parentElement.appendChild(document.createElement('main-element'));
}

// ...
```

When I run a dev playground that uses this library, nothing shows up on the screen.  Also, 'main-element.ts' isn't loaded as one of the source files.  If however I change 'module.ts' to actually import the file and do something dumb with the class, it does work:

```
// module.ts
// import { MainElement } from './components/main-element.ts'; // ADD THIS
// ...

createWindow(context: MyWindowContext): void {
  const element: MainElement = new MainElement(); // ADD THIS
  console.log(element.isConnected); // ADD THIS
  context.parentElement.appendChild(document.createElement('main-element'));
}

// ...
```

So it's clear that he 'main-element.ts' is not being picked up as part of the bundling because it's not explicitly being imported anywhere along the chain.  I assume there is something I can add to my Webpack configuration that will load these web component files?  Is there another way for these web components to be consumed?

Thanks in advance!

- Steve

Comment: I'm facing same problem, My lit project works fine. but when I try to consume my web component into react project it falls into error of could not resolve path. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**You need to import files to be able to use them. There needs to be an import statement somewhere for Webpack to know to include that file in the bundle.**

If all you care about is loading the web component, you could also import it like this

`import './components/main-element.ts'`;

This will run the custom elements definition function

`window.customElements.define('main-element', MainElement);`

which adds the web component to the browser's customElement registry.

Doing it this way

`import { MainElement } from './components/main-element.ts';`

is importing the MainElement class. It has the side effect of calling `customElements.define` as well since it's just placed in the file, and when that file is imported, that function will execute.